# Any way to sign mails in Gmail with S/MIME?

Tags: firefox, email, gmail, smime

i am using S/MIME to sign my mails in Thunderbird and Apple Mail on my iOS devices. But from time to time i also use the Gmail webmailer. Is there any working pluging for Mozilla Firefox to also sign Gmail mails in the webmailer with S/MIME?

[Penagon](https://www.penango.com/products) does not support the current version of Firefox. [Mailvelope](http://www.mailvelope.com/) looks good, but only supports PGP/MIME but not S/MIME. The [Gmail S/MIME](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/gmail-smime/) addon for Firefox seems to be outdates as well.

Are there any working alternatives? I cannot belive that there is no solution to sign Gmail messages with S/MIME.

Comment: Related: [How can I get Gmail to support S/MIME?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13802)

Answer (score 0):

Penango are currently working on support for Firefox 24, and expect to have their plugin completed soon.  You might like to get in touch with Michael Sylvester of Penango Inc. (msylvester at penango dot com)  to find out how they are getting on and encourage them.

In the meantime, if you are unable or unwilling to use OpenPGP (Mailvelope, which is very good), the only alternative seems to be Secure Streak for Chrome, which enables you to encrypt e-mails and send them for decryption by a recipient using the same browser and plugin - but you need to exchange the password by another channel (e.g. telephone) because this is not a public-key S/MIME method.  They seem to use the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (see http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/), which is based around AES, and so is extremely secure encryption.